# React Native Firebase setup for both iOS and Android

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm building a simple app in React Native using Expo. I'd like to use the React Native Firebase library so I have access to things like Google/Apple oauth and analytics. I'm reading through the "getting started" docs at rnfirebase.io. There are sections for "Android Setup" and "iOS Setup". However, they don't specify if you can can use both on the same project. The reason for using React Native is so that I can deploy to iOS and Android simultaneously. Can anyone offer any clarity on this or point me in the direction of some less ambiguous documentation? Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use both at the same time?  Have you tried? What's the specific problem you're encountering?

Comment: My problem is that the documentation is unclear - to the point where it presents the two options as two different flows. I'm hoping someone here may have the relevant experience to save me from wasting time and unnecessarily overcomplicating my project.

Comment: The question is a little vague; are you asking about actually setting up the development environment for each or about the coding once it's been set up? There are in fact two 'flows' but that's because you're developing for two platforms and the environment needs the corresponding resources. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both setup instructions in the same project. They don't interfere in any way.  After successful setup for both iOS and Android, the SDKs should behave identically on both platforms *except* where specifically noted in the documentation for the individual Firebase products that you can work with.

Here is a link to an open source RN app that uses Firebase and builds on both Android and iOS: https://github.com/akiver/wordsreminder

Cross platform integration in this way are being used by production apps.  However, if you have a specific problem at runtime with one of the platforms that isn't discussed in the docs, I'll encourage you to post a new question explaining that in more detail.